# Is there a library for converting nano seconds to human-readable strings?

Tags: library, java, time

Suppose I have a Bucket4J time limiter and want to return a clear, helpful message in case the rate is exceeded. *This* is not an example of how you return a good response message

```
package com.example.reactivecrptapi.filter;

import com.example.reactivecrptapi.service.bucketResolver.BucketResolver;
import io.github.bucket4j.ConsumptionProbe;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

@Component
public class RateLimitingWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    private final BucketResolver bucketResolver;

    public RateLimitingWebFilter(BucketResolver bucketResolver) {
        this.bucketResolver = bucketResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return bucketResolver.resolveBucket(exchange)
                .map(bucket -> bucket.tryConsumeAndReturnRemaining(1))
                .flatMap(probe -> probe.isConsumed() ?
                        chain.filter(exchange) :
                        write429Response(exchange, probe));
    }

    private Mono<Void> write429Response(ServerWebExchange exchange, ConsumptionProbe probe) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS);
        return writeResponseBody(response, probe);
    }

    private Mono<Void> writeResponseBody(ServerHttpResponse response, ConsumptionProbe probe) {
        String message = MessageFormat.format(
                "Too many requests. Please wait {0} nanoseconds and make another attempt",
                probe.getNanosToWaitForRefill()
        );
        DataBuffer bodyDataBuffer = DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance
                .wrap(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(bodyDataBuffer));
    }
}
```

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
content-length: 89

Too many requests. Please wait 1Â 792Â 904Â 000Â 000 nanoseconds and make another attempt

Response code: 429 (Too Many Requests); Time: 61ms (61 ms); Content length: 89 bytes (89 B)
```

I could write such a utility myself, but I'm sure someone already did

What library can I use to convert nano longs to strings like "1 minute, 3 seconds"?

Please note that `Duration.ofNanos(nanos)` won't work since I would still have to check whether there are non-zero hours, minutes, etc. so that I don't end up with things like "0 day(s), 0 hour(s), 0 second(s), 0 millisecond(s), 100 nanosecond(s)". Making those checks would in effect result in my own library of sorts

Comment: I don't know about Java, but this is normally called "relative time" or in this case "relative duration". Building a function like `formatDuration` yourself is normally a matter of ~30 minutes, which makes existing libraries less likely.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40487511/7264739 which also has some library answers, although using libs for such trivial purposes is cluttering the app IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out [PrettyTime](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) library?

It allows you to create human-readable, relative timestamps, and very customizable.

For usage, you can check out the [PrettyTimeTest.java](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/ocpsoft/prettytime/PrettyTimeTest.java).